# Updating Shiny sliderInput using updateSliderInput with range

Tags: r, input, shiny, slider, range

I have a `sliderInput` (receiver) that I would like to have it updated from another `sliderInput` (controller). My code works when I pass just one input for the value argument in `updateSliderInput`, however if I pass a vector for the range from receiver, it doesn't work.

In the code below I have provided both sliders that work and doesn't work. How could I make `updateSliderInput` take in a vector of values for a range?

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(

  ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(4, sliderInput("controller", "Controller:", min = 0, max = 50, value = c(10,20)))
        ,column(4, sliderInput("receiver1", "Receiver 1 - Works with 1 value input", min=0, max=20, value=10, step=1))
        ,column(4, sliderInput("receiver2", "Receiver 2 - Doesn't work with 2 values in a vector", min=0, max=20, value=10, step=1))
    )

    ,fluidRow(column(4, verbatimTextOutput("range1")))
    ,fluidRow(column(4, verbatimTextOutput("range2")))

  )

  ,server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
      updateSliderInput(session = session, "receiver1", value = c(input$controller[1]), min = 0, max = 100)
      updateSliderInput(session = session, "receiver2", value = c(input$controller[1],input$controller[2]), min = 0, max = 100)
    })

    output$range1 <- renderPrint({input$controller[1]})
    output$range2 <- renderPrint({input$controller[2]})
  }

)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You gave a single value to `receiver1` and `receiver2` in `ui`, therefore they only accept one value in `updateSliderInput`. If you put a vector of two values in `receiver2`, it will accept the two values of `controller` in `updateSliderInput`.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(

  ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(4, sliderInput("controller", "Controller:", min = 0, max = 50, value = c(10,20)))
      ,column(4, sliderInput("receiver1", "Receiver 1 - Works with 1 value input", min=0, max=20, value=10, step=1))
      ,column(4, sliderInput("receiver2", "Receiver 2 - Doesn't work with 2 values in a vector", min=0, max=20, value=c(0, 10), step=1))
    )

    ,fluidRow(column(4, verbatimTextOutput("range1")))
    ,fluidRow(column(4, verbatimTextOutput("range2")))

  )

  ,server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
      updateSliderInput(session = session, "receiver1", value = c(input$controller[1]), min = 0, max = 100)
      updateSliderInput(session = session, "receiver2", value = c(input$controller[1],input$controller[2]), min = 0, max = 100)
    })

    output$range1 <- renderPrint({input$controller[1]})
    output$range2 <- renderPrint({input$controller[2]})
  }

)
```

Comment: D'oh you wouldn't believe how long I spent looking at this. Thanks!